# Vb sql Accept Changes

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have made a SQL table within Visual Basic 2012.
I then made my dataset for inserting data. 
I made a form and linked it to the table adapter and when the program is running it allows the data to be added to the table but when I reopen the application that data is not there. 
I have tried two acceptchanges but they don't work. So it is not saving it the data that is in the "temporary table".

```
  Me.TableTableAdapter1.InsertQuery(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, Dropdownseats.Text, dropdriver.Text)
    BusesDataSet1.Table.AcceptChanges()
    BusesDataSet1.AcceptChanges()
```

Does anyone one know why this is happening?????

*Changed the database to MS Access and I am still having problems. *

Comment: "I have made a SQL table within Visual Basic 2012." What exactly does that mean? Where do you expect to be persisting the data?

Comment: In the data Source box I added a new source and created the table within that. What I need it to do now is to save when I close the application.

Comment: Try reading the manual on AcceptChanges.  It just marks the data as being updated.  It doesn't actually perform an update.

Comment: Non of this helps, I can add row to data base but it wont save.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ms access's SQL interface, but other SQL implementations use `.Commit()` or `.SaveChanges()` to apply changes (depending on transaction usage). I'm assuming you're not using a Unit of Work pattern as you haven't mentioned it. Oh, also double-check that you're providing a file path and reusing it - otherwise it might be creating a new database every time you run. Finally, unless you _really_ have a reason, don't use MS Access for new projects. Use SQLite (or SQLExpress). They're updated more frequently, have much more features/better integration and are far less clunky